how disable ng2 smart table row selection
This is my tableSettings
 getSafetyTableSettings() {
    this.settingsSafety = {
      hideSubHeader: true,
      actions: false,
      selectMode:'multi',
      noDataMessage: this.translate.instant('stressCheck.implPlan.table.noDataMessage'),
      pager: false,
      rowClassFunction: (row) => {
        return {
          'disabled-row': this.isRowDisabled(row)
        };
      },
      columns: {

And in here i disable the checkboxes like this
 isRowDisabled(row) {
    const index = this.surverData?.payload?.findIndex(item => item === row);
    
    if (index > 0) {
      const previousRow = this.surverData.payload[index - 1];
      return previousRow.endedDateTime 
        && moment(previousRow.endedDateTime).isBefore(moment());
    }
    
    return false;
  }

I want to disable the row selection in the ngx-data-table also at the same time how do i do it ?
this is onRowSelect event for you refernce
onRowSelect(event) {
    const rowData = event.data;
    const rowIndex = this.surverData?.payload.findIndex(item => item.refId === rowData.refId);
    const isCheckboxDisabled = rowIndex !== -1 &&
      this.surverData.payload[rowIndex].endedDateTime &&
      moment(this.surverData.payload[rowIndex].endedDateTime).isBefore(moment());
  
    if (isCheckboxDisabled) {
      event.isSelected = false;
      event.selected = event.selected.filter(row => row.refId !== rowData.refId);
    } else if (event.isSelected) {
      this.selectedRows = event.selected.filter(row => !row.disabled);
    }
    this.resendPopButton = (this.selectedRows && this.selectedRows.length > 0);
    console.log(" ~ StatusListMainComponent ~ onRowSelect ~ event:", event);
    console.log(" ~ Selected Rows:", this.selectedRows);
  }
  
  
}

I tried multipes things but non worked
